# Why context null when using thread?

Tags: multithreading, jsf

I am using primefaces 3.2, i have a problem while using a thread in JSF. I couldn't get a reference to the current `FacesContext` from that thread.

How to get a reference to that context inside that thread.

Comment: 'FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();' Just i have created runnable thread and try to create the faces context object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `FacesContext` is stored in a static thread-local variable. Servlet containers use a specific thread to process each request/response that arrives to the container so, storing the `FacesContext` in a thread-local variable ensures that there is just one instance per request processing lifecycle, which is how it should be.

When you try to obtain a reference to a `FacesContext` from another thread what happens is, since the it's stored as a thread-local variable and since your new thread didn't initialized it yet: you obtain a `null` reference.

If you want/need a faces context in another new thread the only possible way is to create a new context instance by means of the `FacesContextFactory`. However you will need a reference to a `HttpServletRequest`, a `HttpServletResponse` and a `ServletContext` to instantiate it (and I guess you won't be able to get valid references to those objects from a separate thread).