# primefaces RequestContext inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf-2, primefaces

I am currently working on a JSF project with primefaces. Here I am calling a external .exe file inside a separate thread in the backing bean (view scope). After this process finished,I want to display a primefaces dialog. Here is the code I am using,

```
public void initializeBillValidator(final BigDecimal waitSum){
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                String executable = "Using-CCnet.exe";
                String port = "COM1";
                String waitingTimeInSeconds = "30";
                String uniqueCode = "xyzkj";        
                NativeCodeRunner nativeExe=new NativeCodeRunner();

                startLogFileListner();
                System.out.println("Start to wait............");

                BigDecimal billValidatorAmount = nativeExe.runNativeExe("C:\\shared\\test\\Debug\\", executable, port, waitingTimeInSeconds, waitSum.toPlainString(), uniqueCode);          
                System.out.println("End to wait............");
                totalUpToNow = totalUpToNow.add(billValidatorAmount);
                //Thread.sleep(100);
                tailer.stopTailing();

                logger.info("Bill validator amount ::::: "+billValidatorAmount+" totalUpToNow "+totalUpToNow);
                if(null!=billValidatorAmount && billValidatorAmount.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0))!=0){
                    if(totalUpToNow.compareTo(enteredAmount) == -1){
                        showProceedDialog = true;   
                        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('confirmdialogVar').show();");
                    }else if(totalUpToNow.compareTo(enteredAmount) ==0 || totalUpToNow.compareTo(enteredAmount) == 1){
                        showProceedDialog = false;
                        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('proceeddialogVar').show();");
                    }
                }
            };
        }.start();          
}
```

But the issue is I am always getting a null value for RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(). Is this possible to do or is there other ways of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, search before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412718/threads-in-jsf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why context null when using thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263843/why-context-null-when-using-thread)

Comment: As to your actual problem (for which you wrongly thought this was the solution), use push / event mechanisms. PrimeFaces push is great for this. You can pass the eventbus to the thread and from there 'signal' the client.

Comment: @Kukeltje did you mean something like poll in PrimeFaces?

Comment: poll is an option, but push is more modern